# Sendmail can't find local users (with uppercase letters)

Tags: fedora, users, configuration, sendmail

Sendmail works through sending to a smarthost, but can't find local users.

```
# sendmail -bv  LocalUser@myhost.net
LocalUser@myhost.net... User unknown
# grep LocalUser /var/log/maillog
Sep  8 03:48:30 myhost sendmail[6678]: r887mUs3006678: LocalUser@myhost.net... User unknown
```

but ...

```
# ls /home|grep LocalUser
/LocalUser
```

and ...

```
# grep LocalUser /etc/passwd
LocalUser:x:1001:1001:LocalUser:/home/LocalUser:/bin/bash
```

How can I configure sendmail to find localusers?  How should I diagnose this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sendmail and local users with uppercase letters**

**Diagnose**

Sendmail's default configuration converts local user/mailbox names to all lowercase letters before delivery attempt. In your case email to `LocalUser@myhost.net` is delivered by sendmail to non existing `localuser` instead of existing `LocalUser`.

**Possible fixes**

Do not use usernames with uppercase letters

**OR**

Specify the only right uppercase and lowercase mix (fox given lowercase only string).  It requires modification in `sendmail.mc` and `aliases` files.

http://www.sendmail.org/faq/section4.html#4.17
Subject: Q4.17 -- How do I handle user names with upper-case characters?

sendmail.mc file (requires recompilation into sendmail.cf file):

```
MODIFY_MAILER_FLAGS(`LOCAL', `+u')dnl
```

aliases file (requires recompilation with `newaliases` command):

```
# lowercase version to real for accounts with uppercase letters
localuser: LocalUser
```

Comment: Worked a charm!  Would upvote but my low karma prevents it.  I found the info at http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.17

Comment: http://www.sendmail.org/faq/section4.html#4.17 is redirected to sendmail.com site.